# Add blank/empty page after every page automatically

Tags: page-breaking, printing

I wrote my thesis and my school wants an one-sided print. The printing and binding will be done by a professional bookbinder. They only accept only two sided manuscripts.

---

My `\documentclass`:

```
\documentclass[
11pt,
ngerman,
onehalfspacing,
headsepline,
oneside
]{MastersDoctoralThesis}
```

---

Because of that I need to add a blank page after every page of content. I don't want to do this manually using `\newpage` or `\clearpage` because there are too many pages. Is there any LaTeX command (or package) to do this (automatically)?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Should those empty pages be counted as well?

Comment: All empty pages should NOT be counted.

Comment: can you show code line with `documentclass`? which options you have there?

Comment: @Zarko Ok. Post updated.

Comment: This seems very strange to me, I would expect a binder/printer that was experianced in printing thesis to university thesis standards to be able to handle single-sided printing.

Comment: And printed blank pages have a printing cost? Because considering the cost of home laser prints today, and that any home printer can do that,  maybe will be cheaper print yourself the pages and agree with the  bookbinder only the binding task (or well, search another bookbinder).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A solution with package `atbegshi`. It hooks into `\shipout`, the internal command to ship out a page. The hook (`\AtBeginShipout{...}` adds an empty page before the actual page except for the first.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{atbegshi}
\AtBeginShipoutFirst{%
  \AtBeginShipout{%
    \AtBeginShipoutOriginalShipout\null
  }%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Five pages are generated: 1st page, empty page, 2nd page, empty page, 3rd page.

### Modification with an empty page after the last page

Answer to [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/409249/add-blank-empty-page-after-every-page-automatically/409252?noredirect=1#comment1634144_409252):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{atbegshi}
\AtBeginShipoutFirst{%
  \AtBeginShipout{%
    \AtBeginShipoutOriginalShipout\null
  }%
}

\usepackage{atveryend}
\AfterLastShipout{\AtBeginShipoutOriginalShipout\null}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: On `atbegshi v1.19` see this [issue](https://github.com/ho-tex/atbegshi/issues/1)

Comment: Hi. Thank for this answer. Any trick to get also an empty page after the last page?

Comment: @Marca85 See updated answer.

Answer (score 23):

I would use `pdfpages` to do this after the whole thesis is done, since you really have no need for a document with blank pages except to send to the printer, so it makes sense to keep the two documents separate.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=1-,pagecommand={\null\clearpage}]{thesis.pdf}
\end{document}
```