# Is there a package that lets me compile with a blank page each alternating page?

Tags: packages, blank-page

I am preparing a tutorial worksheet for my students and would like to include an option to let me compile it with a blank page every 2nd page, so that I can then print it 2 pages per sheet in landscape and have space for working out on the right hand side.

I also want to be able to compile it normally and also still be able to make changes, so I don't want to manually insert the pages with an `\ifdefined` switch, because if I make changes, then the place where it should be inserted would change.

At the moment, I am just using `pdftk` to insert blank pages manually, but it would be nice to be able to do it automatically when compiling.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/409249/134144 could be useful.

Comment: see the `pgfpages` package (note `pgfpages` not `pdfpages`). It is described in secion 91 of the tikz/pgf manual. Section 91.1 shows the example you are after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert blank page automatically by using `atbegshi` package. Check out this code

```
\documentclass{article}
%
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\AtBeginShipoutFirst{\AtBeginShipout{\AtBeginShipoutOriginalShipout\null}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}
%
\begin{document}
    \lipsum % dummy text
    \lipsum % dummy text
\end{document}
```

If you print the output on a double pages per sheet, you get:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This answer is shamefully copied from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/409252/91556 . The only added effort is compiling and sharing the output figures.

Comment: Shamefully or shamelessly? :-)

Comment: @Mico It was shamelessly, but then I couldn't escape the shame!!